# How to reduce time complexity of while loop

Tags: list, for-loop, while-loop, time-complexity, list-comprehension

My code currently works but it won't pass a the time complexity test, as in it takes too long.

I want to simplify or speed up the loop somehow, but am not sure how to.

Given an input list, without mutating the input, output a NEW list `T` such that `T` is is generated from the input but getting the first and last elements, then reversing the input, to then getting the first and last input again... and so on.

Example: `[1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [1,6,5,2,3,4]`

I've tried doing some list comprehension, but I don't think while loops can be put into a list comprehension.

```py
def arrange(s):
    x = s.copy()
    T = []
    while len(x) != 0:
        if len(x) == 1:
            T.append(x[0])
            break
        else:
            T.append(x.pop(0))
            T.append(x.pop(-1))
            x.reverse()
    return T
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need any list comprehension (or looping for that matter) at all:

```py
def arrange(s):
    return [s[0], s[-1], *reversed(s[1:-1])]
```

The asterisk (`*`) operator simply unpacks the result of the `reversed()` call (which, as implied, reverses the iterable passed) so that each item in the returned value is included in the list. [Read more here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-star-or-asterisk-operator/).